# SQL command not printing to label

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to output a SQL command to a label. I'm connecting to the database alright but the output isn't correct.

Here is my code

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select SUM(IncCost) FROM Incomings WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) <= GETDATE()");

totalInc.Text = com.ToString();

loadDatabase(com);
```

I'm trying to add up all of the values within `IncCost` that are either today's date or earlier and later dates won't be added until that day.

The output I'm currently getting for the label `totalInc` is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
```

(Also the date I'm using is DD/MM/YYYY and I think I'm converting it to date/time correctly.) Cheers in advance for any help, I'm sure it's an easy fix!

Comment: What result are you expecting from `com.ToString()`? Creating command itself doesn't opens connection and runs the query - you have to do it explicitlly. And `ToString` in this case is just method inherited from `object` and used to output some default representation of object.

Comment: I was assuming the results of the sql command. I'm sorry I'm very new to this I'm still learning the basics

Comment: As I've said - you have to explicitly open `SqlConnection` and query this `SqlCommand` for results (`ExecuteScalar` in your particular case). See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: ok I'll have a look now. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a **connection** to the database first, then you can create a command and **execute it** to fetch data from the database.

Try something like this:

```
// define connection string and query to execute
string connectionString = "server=.;database=YourDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
string query = "Select SUM(IncCost) FROM Incomings WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) <= GETDATE();";

// set up connection to database and query command object
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    // open connection, execute command, close connection
    conn.Open();

    // you can use ExecuteScalar, since your query returns only a single value
    int sumOfIncCost = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    conn.Close();

    // set label text
    totalInc.Text = sumOfIncCost.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the **SQL Query** to be in your label, set `label.Text` to `com.CommandText`.

If you want the **result of executing the SQL Query** to be in your label, execute it and set `label.Text` to the result, e.g. `label.Text = ((int)com.ExecuteScalar()).ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Only 3 Steps are required**

1. Connection

   ```
   using (SqlConnection cnn = New SqlConnection(@"yourconnectionString")
   {
       cnn.Open();    
   }
   ```
2. Sql Command

   ```
   using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"yourconnectionString")
   {
      cnn.Open();    

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SUM(IncCost) FROM Incomings WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) <= GETDATE()", cnn))
      {
      }
   }
   ```
3. Reading Value

   ```
   using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"yourconnectionString")
   {
      cnn.Open();    

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SUM(IncCost) FROM Incomings WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) <= GETDATE()", cnn))
      {
          var oValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
          //Now the value is ready to print
          totalInc.Text = ((decimal)oValue).toString("0.00");
      }
   }
   ```